# How can I show multi-line fields in a XamDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamdatagrid

I have a `XamDataGrid` with `AutoGenerateFields="False"` and a bunch of `Field`s defined.  The data in the grid has new line characters `\n` that literally are showing up as '\n'.  How can I get the grid to show them as actual line breaks and have the fields be capable of displaying multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use value converter to split string using "\n" into multiple lines.
In XAML Set the below FieldLayoutSetting

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"  
           AutoArrangeCells="Never" HighlightAlternateRecords="True"                                                                     
         DataRecordSizingMode="SizedToContentAndFixed"/>
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
```

then change the editor style of the Field to Text Wrap

```
<igDP:TextField  Name="Info" Label="Description" Column="6" Row="0" 
        Width="4*" Converter="{StaticResource InfoToStringConverter}" >
         <igDP:TextField.Settings>
                            <igDP:FieldSettings >
                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}">
                                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                    </Style>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                        </igDP:TextField.Settings>
                    </igDP:TextField>
```

I tested it and it displays multiple lines correctly